# New-Item recursive registry keys

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line, registry

With PowerShell you can run a command like this

```
ni c:/foo/bar -type directory
```

and it will create `foo` and `bar` as necessary. However if you run

```
ni hklm:software/classes/firefoxhtml/shell/edit/command -type directory
```

all keys but the last must exist or an error will be generated. Can PowerShell generate the parent keys as needed?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was just missing the `-force` parameter

```
New-Item hklm:software/classes/firefoxhtml/shell/edit/command -Force
```

Using `-Force` will also remove everything under the key if it already exists so a better option would be

```
if(!(Test-Path $path)){
    New-Item $path -Force;
}
```

Comment: That's a trap for young players.  Very good to know.